# Angular - efficient way to check how many inputs are not empty in large template driven form

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have multiple large Angular 11 template forms with basic inputs (text, radiolist, checkboxes). what is the most efficient way to go about calculating the percentage of the inputs are completed as the user is working on it. (number of not empty inputs / total number of inputs in form). I'm using ngModel binding on all the fields. Not sure how to go about writing a custom validation for this.

Comment: If there are two way binding in all fields, can't you check the number of empty fields w.r.t the total?

Answer (score 2):

## Counting filled inputs utilizing a directive and a service to manage state

- We create a directive to trigger updates when changes happen to the element.
- We utilize a service to hold the state information of our form

**caveats:** Note the following things:

- The Service is currently provided in root, which will mean it will only work for a single form. If you need multiple forms you need to either provide the service at a component level, and bake each form into this component, or extend the state logic to handle multiple forms via keys or similar.
- You may wish to replace the service with more sophisticated state management schemes. I chose to utilize a service for its simplicity.

**Note:** this solution recalculates the entire percentage count every time any input is changed. This was chosen to favor its simplicity in implementation. For larger forms it may be better to check in the directive whether an input has already been counted or not, by setting a flag when the input changes from filled to empty and vise versa.

## The Directive

We make an assumption that the directive will only be utilized on `HTMLInputElement` types.

```
@Directive({selector: '[countInput]'})
export class CountInputDirective implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {

  private subscription = new Subscription();

  constructor(private host: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>, private countService: CountingService) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.countService.addInput(this.host.nativeElement);
    this.subscription.add(
      fromEvent(this.host.nativeElement, 'keydown')
        .pipe(debounceTime(350))
        .subscribe(change => {
          this.countService.inputStateChanged()
        })
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    this.countService.removeInput(this.host.nativeElement);
  }
}
```

You may want to change the event binding as is appropriate for your use-case if not all of your inputs support key events.

## The Service

```js
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class CountingService {
  private _inputs: HTMLInputElement[] = [];
  private formUpdateEvent: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter();
  private _filled: number = 0;

  get total() {
    return this._inputs.length;
  }

  get percentageDone() {
    return Math.round(this._filled / Math.max(this.total, 1) * 100);
  }

  get formUpdated() {
    return this.formUpdateEvent.asObservable();
  }

  addInput(element: HTMLInputElement) {
    this._inputs.push(element);
  }

  removeInput(element: HTMLInputElement) {
    const index = this._inputs.indexOf(element);
    if (index > -1) {
      this._inputs.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }

  inputStateChanged() {
    this.recalculateState();
    this.formUpdateEvent.emit();
  }

  private recalculateState() {
    this._filled = 0;
    this._inputs.forEach(element => {
      if (Boolean(element.value))
        this._filled++;
    });
  }
  
}
```

## Using the solution

If we need to trigger some logic when a change occurs we can subscribe to the provided `EventEmitter` however if we merely want to display the total percentage we can just access the getter directly.

```js
@Component()
 // inject the service in the component with your form.
 constructor(private count: CountingService) {}
```

```
<!-- apply the directive to all inputs that need to be counted -->
<form action="">
  <input type="text" countInput>
  <input type="text" countInput>
  <input type="text" countInput>
</form>
{{count.percentageDone}}
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using template driven for then we can not add custom validation to form directly. But there is a way we can achieve it. Control for which you want that custom validation logic, we can apply input change event and handle it separately.
Now with respect to detect progress of that large form, you can divide the large form in smaller form groups and handle events like on input change event for that form group. In this way we can avoid iterating over large collection of form controls if we apply input change event to form itself.